# Clickable area of an imageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, scrollview

I have a scroll view with 1 child. a linear layout that has many children, each is a "row" containing 5 image views. What I want to happen is when you click on an image it launches a new activity. However, the issue is that it seems touching only the top half of an image actually is registered as a "click" on the image you actually pressed, and anything else in the bottom half of the image is registered as a "click" of the image directly below the image you actually pressed. I am using a nexus 7 2013 for testing, and each thumbnail is 100 x 100 so I am considering that as a reason why, but is there a way to make sure the image you press is actually what is registered?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="150" android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="dp"
            android:layout_weight="10" android:paddingTop="-50dp" android:layout_marginTop="-50dp">
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p1"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

                </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p2"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p3"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p4"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/p5"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:layout_weight="10" android:paddingTop="-50dp" android:layout_marginTop="-135dp">
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p6"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p7"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p8"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p9"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/p10"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:layout_weight="10" android:paddingTop="-50dp" android:layout_marginTop="-135dp">
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p11"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p12"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p13"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p14"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/p15"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:layout_weight="10" android:paddingTop="-50dp" android:layout_marginTop="-135dp">
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p16"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p17"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p18"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p19"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/p20"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:layout_weight="10" android:paddingTop="-50dp" android:layout_marginTop="-135dp">
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p21"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p22"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p23"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p24"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/p25"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:layout_weight="10" android:paddingTop="-50dp" android:layout_marginTop="-135dp">
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p26"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p27"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p28"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p29"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/p30"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:layout_weight="10" android:paddingTop="-50dp" android:layout_marginTop="-135dp">
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p31"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p32"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p33"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p34"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/p35"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:layout_weight="10" android:paddingTop="-50dp" android:layout_marginTop="-135dp">
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p36"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p37"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p38"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p39"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/p40"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:layout_weight="10" android:paddingTop="-50dp" android:layout_marginTop="-135dp">
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p41"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p42"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p43"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p44"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/p45"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:layout_weight="10" android:paddingTop="-50dp" android:layout_marginTop="-135dp">
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p46"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p47"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p48"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p49"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/p50"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:layout_weight="10" android:paddingTop="-50dp" android:layout_marginTop="-135dp">
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p51"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p52"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p53"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p54"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/p55"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:layout_weight="10" android:paddingTop="-50dp" android:layout_marginTop="-135dp">
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p56"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p57"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p58"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p59"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/p60"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:layout_weight="10" android:paddingTop="-50dp" android:layout_marginTop="-135dp">
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p61"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p62"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p63"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p64"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/p65"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:layout_weight="10" android:paddingTop="-50dp" android:layout_marginTop="-135dp">
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p66"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p67"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p68"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p69"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/p70"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:layout_weight="10" android:paddingTop="-50dp" android:layout_marginTop="-135dp">
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p71"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p72"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p73"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/p74"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/p75"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>










    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: You have a problem with your layout. We need to see the layout XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is due to negative padding and margins on successive linear layout rows.

Highly recommend you switch to `GridLayout` which is designed for the purpose you are trying to achieve, as your layout is a little bit hard to manage I think.